# Yii2 Working with AJAX for get values

Tags: php, json, ajax, yii2

i have _form.php field

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

   <?= $form->field($model, 'IdKaryawan')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => $listData,
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Karyawan...','id'=>'Nomor'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]); ?>

    <?=  $form->field($model, 'IdJabDepAwal')->textInput(['maxlength' => 100])?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'IdJabDep')->textInput(['maxlength' => 100])?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'Alasan')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'Status')->textarea(['rows' => 6])?>
```

it work just fine until i put this to fill the value below

```
 $script = <<< JS
    $('#Nomor').change(function(){
        var test = $(this).val();
        $.get('karyawan/get-IdJabDept',{ test : test },function(data){
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#mutasi-IdJabDepAwal').attr('value',data.IdJabDept);

        });
    });

    JS;
    $this->registerJs($script);
```

the field IdJabDept wont updated.
how do i fix my code ?
any helps is appriciated,

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#mutasi-IdJabDepAwal').attr('value',data.IdJabDept);
```

to

```
$("#mutasi-IdJabDepAwal").val(data.IdJabDept);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$.get('karyawan/get-IdJabDept',{ test : test },function(data){
```

for this:

```
$.get('index.php?r=karyawan/get-IdJabDept',{ test : test },function(data){
```